# How to give css style to Radio button

Tags: html, css, sass

how to give css style to Radio button, and should work on Mac, safari and Chrome too

```
  <form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
  </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize radio button in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270168/how-to-customize-radio-button-in-html)

Comment: You can get some inspiration from https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/Eypnq

Comment: Also we are not here to code for you. You have to show us what you have worked and tried so far,  so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this into your CSS-File.

```
input[type="radio"] {
    ... your declarations here ...
}
```

This is the selector for your radios.

---

**NOTE:**
This will affect other radios on your site too. It would be better if you wrap your radios with a `div` or other tags and give the tag a specific `id`. Then you could select the radios inside the id like this:

```
#yourDivId input[type="radio"] {
    ... your declarations here ...
}
```

Comment: @MoshFeu He didn't asked a precise question. He wanted to give a style to his radios and thats how he could do it.

Comment: It's hard to believe that he just looking for a selector, but maybe it's just me..

Comment: @MoshFeu I think we'll never know.