# How to select radio/chekbox buttons for styling?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to style my radio/checkbox buttons, and I saw a lot of snippets for the checked | before | after pseudo elements, which looked something like this:

```
input[type="radio"] + label:before
```

But this refers to the html tag order, for example:

```
<input type="radio" id="male" />
<label for="male"> Male </label>
```

Which is only useful if the button is placed before the text.
I used:

```
<label for="male"> Male 
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" />
</label>
```

In this case how do I select the button? 
And hypothetically, how do I select it if my code looked like this:

```
 <label for="male"> Male </label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" />
```

My [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/BxVYzv) (It's a little bit messy right now-working on alignment)

Comment: Are you styling the `<label>` or the `<input>`? Please include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate your issue.

Comment: If that is the code you are using, why not use the id that already exists for the input to style it? You have an id set to `"male"` already.

Comment: If you just want to style input radio/checkbox then use "input[type="radio"]" and then add your css.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/4148544#4148544) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758774/how-to-give-css-style-to-radio-button) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561970/css-style-radio-button-with-label-next-to-it)

Comment: Can you all elaborate a little please ? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

For CSS Chx/Rad Hack you need to do the following:

- All `<input type='radio/checkbox'>` have `display;none`
- Each paired `<label/input>` has

  `<label for='input#ID'...`
    `<input id='input#ID'...`
- Each pair is positioned so the Adjacent Sibling Combinator `+` can be used with tight control.:

  `<input>`
    `<label></label>`
    `.rad:checked + label::before`

---

## Demo

#### Modications are Commented in Demo

---

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura|Lobster");
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


/* styles to make borders not take on extra space */

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* fix for the scrollbar push issue */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Browser style reset so they all play nice */

html,
body,
div,
span,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
abbr,
address,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
samp,
small,
strong,
sub,
sup,
var,
b,
i,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0 none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* Now we Starting to code */

body {
  background-color: #FAFDD9;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48pt;
  color: #08ABD9;
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 8x;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  border-color: white;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'jura', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17pt;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

legend {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'jura', sans-serif;
}

select,
input[type="number"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-style {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #001d26 1%, #103842 47%, #001d26 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #001d26 1%, #103842 47%, #001d26 100%);
  background: linear-gradient (-45deg, #001d26 1%, #103842 47%, #001d26 100%);
  border: 6px solid #08ABD9;
  border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(29, 31, 32, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(29, 31, 32, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(29, 31, 32, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(29, 31, 32, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(29, 31, 32, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(29, 31, 32, 0.8);
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80x;
}

label,
legend {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'jura', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*tried to change from column to row */

#fname,
#email-a,
#phone,
#dropdown,
#mrole,
#age,
#textbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#fname label,
#email-a label,
#phone label,
#dropdown label,
#mrole label,
#age label,
#player label,
#textbox label,
legend {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#fname input,
#email-a input,
#phone input,
#dropdown select,
#mrole select,
#age input,
#textbox textarea {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-family: 'roboo', sans-serif;
}

#gender {
  margin: auto;
}

#player input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

select {
  vertical-align: top;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  background-color: #08ABD9;
  font-family: 'jura', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: #0792B9;
}

#fname,
#email-a {
  margin:
}

"#name",
"#email",
"#number",
#gil,
select,
textarea {
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 32px;
}

input,
select {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

textarea {
  height: 160px;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #08ABD9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px #08ABD9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px #08ABD9;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px #08ABD9;
}


/* CSS Modifications */

input,
select {
  font: inherit
}

.rad,
.chx {
  display: none;
}

.rad+label,
.chx+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rad+label::before {
  content: '\1f518';
  box-shadow: -0.25px 2.5px 2px 1.25px rgba(21, 91, 131, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rad:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f535';
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 2.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
}

.chx+label::before {
  content: '\1f532';
  box-shadow: -0.25px 2.5px 2px 1.25px rgba(21, 91, 131, 0.7);
  height: 36px;
  width: 36x;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  font-size: 3ex;
}

#guitar:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f3b8';
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
  color: rgba(242, 244, 250, 0.8);
  font-size: 3ex;
}

#bass:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f3b8';
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
  color: rgba(242, 244, 250, 0.8);
  font-size: 3ex;
}

#drums:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f941';
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
  color: rgba(242, 244, 250, 0.8);
  font-size: 3ex;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0
}

#fiddle:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f3bb';
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
  color: rgba(242, 244, 250, 0.8);
  font-size: 3ex;
}

#saxophone:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f3b7';
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
  color: rgba(242, 244, 250, 0.8);
  font-size: 3ex;
}

#other:checked+label::before {
  content: '\1f3bc';
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1.2px rgba(38, 114, 141, 0.7);
  color: rgba(242, 244, 250, 0.8);
  font-size: 3ex;
}

#textbox,
#mrole {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

  <form class="form-style">

    <fieldset class="container">

      <h1 id="title"> Music - Survey Form </h1>

      <div id="description">
        <p> Lets Find Out What Kind Of Music You Like</p>
      </div>

      <div id="fname">
        <label for="name"> Full Name *</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="What's your name" required />

      </div>

      <div id="email-a">
        <label for="email">  Email * </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="What's your email" required />

      </div>

      <div id="phone">
        <label for="number"> Phone </label>
        <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="what's your number" />
      </div>

      <fieldset id="gender">

        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" class='rad' />
        <label for="male"> Male </label>

        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" class='rad' />
        <label for="female"> Female </label>

      </fieldset>

      <div id="age">
        <label for="gil"> Age</label>
        <input type="number" id="gil" />

      </div>

      <fieldset id="frequent">
        <legend> How Frequent Do You Listen To Music </legend>

        <input type="radio" id="aday" name="frequent" class='rad' />
        <label for="aday">All day </label>

        <input type="radio" id="eday" name="frequent" class='rad' />
        <label for="eday">Every day </label>

        <input type="radio" id="oday" name="frequent" class='rad' />
        <label for="oday">Every other day </label>

        <input type="radio" id="party" name="frequent" class='rad' />
        <label for="party">I'm a party person </label>
      </fieldset>

      <div id="mrole">
        <label for="role"> Which Best Describes Your Main Role?</label>
        <select name="role">
          <option value=""> Select an option </option>
          <option value="Student"> Student </option>
          <option value="Military"> Military </option>
          <option value="Academic"> Academic </option>
          <option value="Full time job"> Full Time Job </option>
          <option value="Prefer Not To Say"> Prefer Not To Say</option>
          <option value="Other"> Other</option>

        </select>
      </div>

      <div id="dropdown">
        <label for="gener"> Choose A Music Genre </label>
        <select name="gener">
          <option value=""> Select an option </option>
          <option value="African"> African </option>
          <option value="Asian"> Asian </option>
          <option value="Avant-garde"> Avant-garde </option>
          <option value="Blues"> Blues </option>
          <option value="Caribbean"> Caribbean </option>
          <option value="Country"> Country </option>
          <option value="Electronic"> Electronic </option>
          <option value="Hip hop"> Hip hop </option>
          <option value="Jazz"> Jazz </option>
          <option value="Folk"> Folk </option>
          <option value="Latin"> Latin </option>
          <option value="Other"> other </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <fieldset id="player">
        <legend> Let Us Know If Play An Instrument </legend>

        <input type="checkbox" id="guitar" class='chx' />
        <label for="guitar"> Guitar </label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="bass" class='chx' />
        <label for="bass"> Bass Guitar </label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="drums" class='chx' />
        <label for="drums"> Drums </label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="fiddle" class='chx' />
        <label for="fiddle"> Fiddle </label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="saxophone" class='chx' />
        <label for="saxophone"> Saxophone </label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="other" class='chx' />
        <label for="other"> Other </label>

      </fieldset>

      <div id="textbox">
        <label for="tbox">Please Tell Us More About Your Self</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="tbox"></textarea>

      </div>

      <div id="btn">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

      </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Closing div-container -->
    </fieldset>

  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I, don't know if it's the right place for that, but can you explain a little what you did and why? p.s if it more suitable for this, I can give you my FB address

Comment: I'v tried it an it didn't work for me, this is my codepen (forked) with the changing: https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/Xqyedo

Comment: In my answer, the layout has each input *before* the label. The `<input>`'s next **sibling** is :`+` an `<label>`. Your layout has the `<label>` as a **parent** of the `<input>`. Move the `<input>` out of the `<label>` and place it right before the `<label>`.  Anyways, that's a good sign that you are trying to learn because you wouldn't get that mistake if you just cut and paste the code. Let me know if you need further assistance I'll be happy to help.

Comment: BTW I noticed that there's the default checkboxes showing up it's because the class you gave them is `.chk` and the class is .ch**x** in CSS